# Check that $F:A/\mathfrak p\longrightarrow B/\mathfrak q$ is well defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

Let $A,B$ commutative rings and $\mathfrak p,\mathfrak q$ ideals of $A$ and $B$ respectively. We define $$F:A/\mathfrak p\longrightarrow B/\mathfrak q$$
by $$F(a+\mathfrak p)=f(a)+\mathfrak q$$
where $f:A\longrightarrow B$ is ring homomorphism and $\mathfrak q$ is the ideal generated by $f(\mathfrak p)$. I want to check that $F$ is well defined. The problem is that it looks too simple since usually to check that such functions are well defined is more complicate. So is it correct ?

Let $a+\mathfrak p=b+\mathfrak p$. Since $\mathfrak p$ is an ideal, we have that $a-b\in \mathfrak p$. Therefore, $$F(a+\mathfrak p)=F(a+b-b+\mathfrak p)=F(b+(a-b)+\mathfrak p)=F(b+\mathfrak p).$$

Is it correct ? In fact, even if $A$ is not a commutative ring it works, no ? Since $(A,+)$ is always a commutative group. Can I then deduce that if $A$ is a ring and $I$ is a both side ideal, then all function $$F:A/I\longrightarrow B$$
is well defined ?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine...and simple, indeed.

Comment: You don't mean $\mathfrak p=f^{-1}\mathfrak q$?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thank you very much :)

Comment: I happened to stumble upon [this blog post by Timothy Gowers](https://gowers.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/why-arent-all-functions-well-defined/) just now and in it he basically addresses this very question. It's a long read, but if you have the time and enough patience then it should be worth it. If you don't have the time then the tl;dr version is: your "definition" of $F$ only actually defines a multi-valued function, and to "check well-defined" you need to check that this multi-valued function is in fact a function, i.e., check that it is single-valued. This amounts to the same as my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct in the idea, but you skip over important details by using $F(a+\mathfrak{p})$ before actually checking the map exists, so you skip over an important point. In your proof you use an argument that may look circular. If you use the $f$ version, you have
$$
f(a)+\mathfrak{p}=f(a+b-b)+\mathfrak{p}=f(b)+f(a-b)+\mathfrak{p}=f(b)+\mathfrak{p}
$$

You can improve and simplify it by observing that $a-b\in\mathfrak{p}$ implies $f(a)-f(b)=f(a-b)\in f(\mathfrak{p})\subseteq\mathfrak{q}$ and therefore $f(a)+\mathfrak{q}=f(b)+\mathfrak{q}$.

You can also “abstract” it.

Let $f\colon A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism; if $\mathfrak{p}$ is an ideal of $A$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ is the ideal of $B$ generated by $f(\mathfrak{p})$, we can consider the ring homomorphism
$$
g=\pi\circ f\colon A\to B/\mathfrak{q}
$$
where $\pi\colon B\to B/\mathfrak{q}$ is the canonical projection. If $a\in\mathfrak{p}$, then $f(a)\in\mathfrak{q}$ and so $g(a)=0$. Hence $a\in\ker g$.

The homomorphism theorem now says that there is a unique ring homomorphism $F\colon A/\mathfrak{p}\to B/\mathfrak{q}$ such that $F(a+\mathfrak{p})=g(a)=\pi\circ f(a)=f(a)+\mathfrak{q}$.

---

About your last question, it is not clear what you mean. What is true is that a ring homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ induces a ring homomorphism $f_I\colon A/I\to B$, for all ideals $I$ such that $I\subseteq\ker f$. This is already contained in the previous statement, because in this case $f(I)=\{0\}$.

Comment: How can you say that OP's solution is correct, when he never used $f(\mathfrak p)\subseteq \mathfrak q$ in his proof of well-definedness? Also, you use the same argument as me, but say that mine is unnecessarly complicated, when in fact it is exactly what has to be done, when proving well-definedness.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct. You have to show the equality $F(b+(a-b)+\mathfrak p) = F(b+\mathfrak p)$: this is, where you actually use different representatives.

**In other words:** If we have $a+\mathfrak p = b+\mathfrak p$, then $a$ and $b$ are different representatives of the same coset. The definition of $F(a+\mathfrak p)$ depends on the representative $a$. To show well-definedness, you need to show that for a different representative $b$ we have $F(a+\mathfrak p) = F(b+\mathfrak p)$. Now, $b+a-b$ and $a$ are the same representatives (i.e. $b+a-b= a$), so that $F(a+\mathfrak p) = F(b+a-b+\mathfrak p)$ is trivial. But $b+a-b$ and $b$ are different representatives for the same coset, so that $F(b+a-b+\mathfrak p) = F(b+\mathfrak p)$ is to be shown. At some point, you have to make use of the actual definition of $F$.

Notice that $f(\mathfrak p) \subseteq \mathfrak q$ and hence, if $a+\mathfrak p = b+\mathfrak p$, then $b-a\in \mathfrak p$, i.e. $f(b-a)\in \mathfrak q$ and thus
\begin{align*}
F(a+\mathfrak p) &= f(a) + \mathfrak q = f(a) + f(b-a) + \mathfrak q\\
&= f(a+b-a) + \mathfrak q = f(b) + \mathfrak q\\
&= F(b+\mathfrak p).
\end{align*}

You could also apply the homomorphism theorem for rings to the composition $A\stackrel{f}{\to} B\to B/\mathfrak q$ (whose kernel is $\mathfrak p = f^{-1}\mathfrak q$), where $B\to B/\mathfrak q$ is the canonical projection.

Comment: I don't understand. If $a-b\in \mathfrak p$, we have that $a-b+\mathfrak p=\mathfrak p$, no ? so, $b+a-b+\mathfrak p=\mathfrak p$, no ? then $F(b+(a-b)+\mathfrak p)=F(b+\mathfrak p)$. What's wrong ?

Comment: @usr352653: To deduce from that that the function is well-defined is to assume the conclusion. The point about well-defined-ness is that the function only takes one value for each distinct input, and you have not shown this (in fact, you haven't said anything explicit about the values of the function at all).

Comment: @WillR No, and yes: he showed that for $\;a+\frak p=b+\frak p\;$ then $\;F(a+\frak{p}) ={} F(b+\frak p)$ and this shows well defined.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I would argue that that notation for "function", i.e., $F(\cdot)$, only makes sense for actual functions. That is, you are assuming well-defined even when you make such a statement. You need to say something in terms of $f(a)+\mathfrak{p}$ for the argument to be sound.

Comment: @WillR I beg to difer. Before the proof of soundness is done, $\;F(a+\frak p)\;$ is just the notation for a *relation* . Once good-definiteness is proved it is already a function.

Comment: @DonAntonio: To what, exactly, is the notation $F(a+\mathfrak{p})$ referring, if not the (unique!) value of a function (which we don't yet know is actually a function)? Are you claiming that all relations between a set of cosets and any other set is are actually functions? Why do we ever need to prove well-defined?

Comment: @WillR As you know, any function is a relation, which is only a subset of a cartesian product. Instead of writing $\;R\subset A\times B\;,\;\;aRb\;$ , we can also write $\;f:A\to B\;,\;\;f(a)=b\;$ and etc. In this case, the domain of the **relation** (until otherwise proved) is $\;A/p\;$ and the codomain is $\;B/p\;$ , thus $\;F(a+p)\;$ is *the relation* $\;F\;$ on $\;a+p\;$ . To prove that relation is *actually* a function you must prove  that every element in the domain has one *unique* image (this is what many beginners confuse with injectivity), or $\;a+p=b+p\implies F(a+p)=F(b+p)\;$ ...

Comment: Cont. ...which is, precisely, what the OP did. I find all this pretty elementary, in particular for a student already messing with abstract algebra at this level (rings, quotient rigns, homomorphisms and etc.)

Comment: @DonAntonio: If you write $f(a)=b$ for $aRb,$ then you are neglecting the possibility that $a$ is related to some other element $c,$ in which case $b=f(a)=c.$ Have you not assumed that $f$ is a function here? You have not answered my last question, namely, why is well-definedness a required part of any proof if such a simple argument works for *almost all* cases of interest (note that this argument requires only an abelian group structure on the set of cosets).

Comment: @DonAntonio: I could understand if $f(a+p)$ were the set of things related to $a+p$, but then you haven't shown that this set is a singleton set, which would be the natural condition for $f$ being a function. I think you'll have shown that the function mapping an element to its set of related elements is well-defined (which is not what was to be shown).

Comment: @WillR I honestly cannot find the way to explain you this without a formal class with a blackboard and chalk. Sorry. This is a-b-c in relations - basic set theory when applied to a rather elementary part of abstract algebra. I haven't assumed *at all* $\;f\;$ is a function **before** it has been proved so and etc. Well definedness of functions is required whenever you try to  work with those things on a set the elements of which can have multiple expressions... **precisely** as with quotient spaces by an equivalence relations, just as quotient rings are...

Comment: @DonAntonio: I know well-definedness is required and I know why. What I don't get is why it needs to be reproven every time if such a simple argument works in all cases of interest. You haven't shown that the set of elements related to $a+p$ is a singleton, therefore I do not think you have not shown well-defined. If you need more time to explain, you have all the time you need: You can post your own answer to the question. This is, after all, what this question is about.

Comment: Of course, in my last comment I meant to say "therefore I do not think you have shown well-defined."

Comment: @WillR It already **must be clear as crystal** at this stage that $\;a+\frak p\;$ is *one single element* (and not "a set" or some other weird being) in the quotient ring, otherwise one needs to go farther back! I do **not** need to show that *in this case*, just as I don't need to show $\;7\cdot8=56\;$ when I teach differential calculus, say. And it is **not** true that "such simple arguments works in all cases of interest": it depends, **of course**, on the definition of the function to be.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Where have you used the "definition of the function to be" when you say $F(a+p)=F(a+b-b+p)=F(b+a-b+p)=F(b+p)?$ Please pinpoint at least one specific instance; all I can see is some manipulation with the group law on the set of cosets. Hundreds of beginning abstract algebra students across the world must lose collectively thousands of marks every year over something that you are claiming can be basically skipped over, if only the lecturer would include this elementary argument as a lemma somewhere in their course.

Comment: @WillR This is already too long and weary (for me, at least). The basics of set theory are usually given in *earlier* courses like Discrete Mathematics, and/or even in basic linear algebra. If they can't handle cosets in ring theory, when they have already studied them in group theory (the usual, standard order of studies, at least as far as I understand it and apply it), then they have, imo, more important and basic things to be worried about.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I'm sorry, but if it is "already too long and weary" for you to pinpoint one use of a single definition in a string of just three equalities, then I do not believe the argument to be so trivial to be reasonably skipped over in such a way and more reasoning must be provided for the argument to be sound. Things to do with well-defined-ness of functions are not given in earlier courses in my university, and, I should not need to add, that is *not* a valid counter-argument regardless. Groups and rings are introduced in the same module and examined in the same exam in that module.

Comment: @WillR My heart bleeds for the students in your university. Good night.

Answer (score 0):

You can try proof that a singular element of $A/p$ it has an only imagen on $B/q$. Let $a_1+p\,a_2+p \in A/p$ and suppose that $a_1+p=a_2+p$ then, $a_1-a_2\in p$ thus, $f(a_1-a_2)=f(a_1)-f(a_2)$ since $f$ is a ring homomorphism. Now, since $p=f^{-1}(q)$ there exist $k\in q$ such that $f(a_1)-f(a_2)=k$ and this implies that $f(a_1)+q=f(a_2)+q$ in other words, $F(a_1+p)=F(a_2+p)$, adn $F$ is well defined.

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to turn my discussion with @DonAntonio in the comments into an actual answer. Since this is heavily influenced by discussion with another user, I have made this answer community wiki. In the course of this answer, I will be talking a lot about relations, rather than functions. At the end, I will say a few words about why we can legitimately skip out all this talk of relations.

When we say we say we define $F\colon A/\mathfrak{p}\to B/\mathfrak{q}$ by $F(a+\mathfrak{p})=f(a)+\mathfrak{q},$ we are not really defining a function here. We have not defined a function until we have shown that the "function" in question is well-defined.

A possible save is to say we are defining a relation between the sets $A/\mathfrak{p}$ and $B/\mathfrak{q},$ a relation $R$ defined by $(a+\mathfrak{p})R(f(a)+\mathfrak{q})$ for all $a\in A.$ Proving "the function is well-defined" is the same thing as proving that "this relation is actually a function," just described in different words. To prove this relation is a function, we need to show that the set of elements in $B/\mathfrak{q}$ related to $a+\mathfrak{p}$ is a singleton set.

First, what does your argument show? If we interpret $F(a+\mathfrak{p})$ to mean "the set of elements related to $a+\mathfrak{p}$", then you have shown that the function mapping each element to its set of related elements is well-defined. This is clearly not the same as showing that the set of elements related to an element is a singleton set, so your argument does not prove that the function is well-defined.

How do we actually prove that $F$ is well-defined? That is, how do we prove that the relation is in fact a function? To do this, **we have to use the definition of the relation** in question. Suppose $a+\mathfrak{p}=b+\mathfrak{p};$ we will show that $f(a)+\mathfrak{q}=f(b)+\mathfrak{q}.$ The point is that if $x,y\in B/\mathfrak{q}$ with $(a+\mathfrak{p})Rx$ and $(b+\mathfrak{p})Ry,$ then for $R$ to define a function we should have $x=y$ if $a+\mathfrak{p}=b+\mathfrak{p};$ but the definition of the relation is that $(a+\mathfrak{p})R(f(a)+\mathfrak{q})$ and $(b+\mathfrak{p})R(f(b)+\mathfrak{q}),$ so it suffices to show that $f(a)+\mathfrak{q}=f(b)+\mathfrak{q}$ whenever $a+\mathfrak{p}=b+\mathfrak{p}.$

Now the actual proof is as follows:

> Suppose $a+\mathfrak{p}=b+\mathfrak{p}.$ Then $a-b\in\mathfrak{p}$ (standard fact), so $f(a)-f(b)=f(a-b)\in\mathfrak{q}$ (by assumptions). Hence $f(a)+\mathfrak{q}=f(b)+\mathfrak{q}$ (the same standard fact).

By our previous remarks, this is all we need to prove that $F$ is well-defined, so now we can continue using $F$ as a function all we like. Note that the little argument in the pink box said nothing about general relations; that's why in general we don't need to say anything about relations. That technical stuff (which appears to me to be somewhat brushed under the rug) is all wrapped up in the preceding paragraph.

---

It is perhaps worth noting that the only real objection I have made is that you have used some notation before checking that the map is indeed a map; but, in my opinion, if this is such a trivial qualm that you can ignore it, then there is no point in explicitly proving well-defined-ness. Put another way, because well-defined-ness is something worth proving, this objection is a valid objection. After all, this is the reason we prove well-defined-ness in the first place.